# Add activity graph to user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

How about adding a chat-like activity graph to the user profiles on SE sites? It might need more processing power, but the information is there in the activity tab.

[image]

Comment: meh, the whole purpose of websites is to *tear down* time, whereas chat is unavoidably and inextricably about time above all else.. getting people in the right place at the right time. Wrong focus IMO.